# Как в js включить поддержку русского языка?

Tags: javascript

Есть модуль сортировки табличных значений `https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html`
Там подключается js, который осуществляет саму сортировку

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

В этом файле есть текстовые элементы, вроде таких `sInfo:"Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",sInfoEmpty:"Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",`

При попытке перевести на русский язык появляются вот такие символы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама страница у меня имеет кодировку utf-8

Comment: В выходном HTML должна быть тоже установлена кодировка.

Answer (score 2):

Для того что бы правильно выводилась кодировка необходимо

Задать кодировку в самом HTML (в том html файле который выводит строчку)

Один из вариантов это прописать в `head`

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    ...
 </head>
```